# Make div height the distance of swipe down

Tags: javascript, jquery, gesture, hammer.js

I'm trying to gradually show a div as the swipe down event happens on the body.

I'm currently using the jQuery version of hammer.js to listen for the swipe down, but **how do I get the distance of the swipe and change the height of the div as the swipe is happening to that value?**

It is not much, but here is what I have so far:

```
var distance;
$('body').on('swipedown', function(){

    // set distance to swipe distance
    $('header, #header, [role="banner"]').css('height', distance);
});
```

But, won't the above only set the distance at the end of the swipe down? How can I set the distance while the swipe down is happening?

I would greatly appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 2):

By hammer.js swipedown event triggered, your function will get a gesture object in the event object.

you can get that like this

```
Hammer(document.body).on('swipedown', function(e){
    gesture = e.gesture

    // gesture.distance or gesture.deltaY is swipe distance
    // and you can console.log(gesture) to find more!
});
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. Wait, I'm trying it. Why isn't this working then when I swipe down: http://jsfiddle.net/ExeXq/1/

Comment: if you use mouse, the hammer event is hard to triggered. I'm not sure, but it probably is frameworks bug? And you should add style for body and html tag {height: 100%} to get maximum detecting area.

Comment: I've increased the touch area of the body and I am using Hammer just like the examples. I am testing on a mobile device. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/ExeXq/3/